# Compiling files on every computer

Tags: compiling

I have a folder with :

- one template,
- a lot of beamer files using this template.

Each beamer document uses the template with the command

`\input{D:/My_Docs/Folder_1/Folder_2/Folder_3/Beamer_Folder_4/Folder_5/Beamer_Template_to_use.tex}`

However, it will be convenient for me that I can compile a beamer file whatever the computer I use (by copying the Beamer_Folder_4 on another computer).
For that purpose, is it possible to modify that code to something like :

`\input{LOCAL_PATHWAY/Beamer_Folder_4/Folder_5/Beamer_Template_to_use}`

because `My_Docs/Folder_1/Folder_2/Folder_3/` is very specific to my computer !

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // You can set pathes in Latex, please consult one of those books. If you prepare several such statements, it should work (if necessary, comment-out, what you don't need). / Or use links on your computers AND refer to said link, which should have the same link-name on each and every system.

Comment: The best is to put your template in a local texmf. 
Then you can simply use `\input{Beamer_Template_to_use}` like you can do with packages and beamer itself.

Comment: But looking what is textmf, I didn't understand how it works, sorry. By the way, if I change the computer I'm working on... Then the textmf won't be on the computer anymore ?

Unless I'm missing information, could you explain me, or give me a useful link if I'm wrong (I'm on windows, then typing commands in the cmd seems difficult - I saw that for Mac I believe)